# how to implement a set of persistent coordinated worker threads

Tags: thread-synchronization

I want to reuse a set of worker threads. Each worker thread performs independent work but they must start and stop processing as a coordinated team. I need an efficient means for each worker thread to block until the main thread tells them *all* to go, and an efficient means for the main thread to block until *all* worker threads are finished.

Each chunk of work will only require some tens of microseconds so the usual approach of creating a set of threads then joining them all involves far too much overhead.

The pseudocode is like the following:

main thread:

```
create N threads

forever
    prepare new independent work for each thread
    tell all N threads to run their part
    wait for all N threads to complete their work
    use results
```

typical worker thread:

```
forever
    wait to run
    do my work
    indicate to main my work is complete
```

My question is how best to perform this signaling and synchronization. I am *not* asking about how to divide up the work or move work to or from each thread; suffice it to say the threads do not interact.

Comment: First thing to come to mind is an event driven approach.  Have each worker thread subscribe to a readySetGo event. (Or the eventHandler can fire off the threads.  Have main subscribe to an allThreadsFinished event.

Comment: This is too broad/opinion-based. For example, I might think that semaphores can be used here, but you've dismissed that approach as too kludgy. How can we know what you won't find kludgy? Try showing a specific attempted solution and explain what specifically you don't like about it.

Comment: @Ken: fair enough, I've edited the question to just ask for suggestions.

Comment: @Ken: so are you going to suggest something constructive or just throw rocks?